# How to add an SelectedItem from Dropdownlist to a <Table> using model List<>

Tags: c#, .net, list, asp.net-mvc-5, ienumerable

I'm working on a page that will add the selected item from a dropdownlist to a List<> using button onclick.

The problem is the new selecteditem is overwriting the old value.

I simply would like to display a table from the selected items like this:

```
#---Model-----Remove-----
1   Model#1       x
2   Model#2       x
3   Model#3       x
4   Model#4       x
5   Model#5       x
-------------------------
```

Please see my code below,

**ModelDescription.cs (model):**

```
 public class ModelDescription
{
    public string modelDesc { get; set; }
}
```

**method in controller:**

```
public ActionResult StockOnHand()
    {
        bindModelDesc();
        return View();
    }

 public void bindModelDesc()
    {
        var mc = db.ModelMaster_tbl.ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> mclist = new List<SelectListItem>();
        mclist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select Model Type--", Value = "0" });
        mclist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select All Model--", Value = "1" });

        foreach (var m in mc.Select(x => x.modelDesc).Distinct())
        {
            mclist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m });

            ViewBag.ModelDescs = mclist;
        }
    }

   public ActionResult AddToListSOH(ModelDescription model)
    {
        var result = new List<ModelDescription>();
        var res = db.ModelMaster_tbl.Where(x => x.modelDesc == model.modelDesc).SingleOrDefault();

        result.Add(new ModelDescription { modelDesc = res.modelDesc });

        return PartialView("AddToListSOH", result);
    }
```

**StockOnHand.cshtml (view):**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("StockOnHand", "PWSupermarket", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stock On Hand</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Generates the buildable quantity of a unit. </p>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            @if (TempData["Message"] != null)
            {
                <span class="text-success"><strong>@TempData["Message"]</strong></span>
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.modelDesc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.modelDesc, ViewBag.ModelDescs as List<SelectListItem>, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-1" type="button" onclick="AddToList()">Add To List</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="foo1" class="mt-2">

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Javascript to render the list of selected items partial view:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

     function AddToList() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddToListSOH", "PWSupermarket")',
            data: { modelDesc: $('#modelDesc').val() },
            contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#foo1').html(result);
            },
            error: function (ex) { alert('failed.'); }
        })
    }

</script>
```

**AddToListSOH.cshtml (Partial View for the list of selected items):**

```
@model IEnumerable<MESProject_P1_csmvc.Models.ModelDescription>

<div>
@{ var count = 0;}
<table class="table table-sm table-striped" @*style="font-size: .7rem;"*@>
    <caption>List of Models</caption>
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                   @count
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.modelDesc)
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[screen shot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XbVx.png)

Comment: You should make List<SelectListItem> in Controller where you can defined Selected true.

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim Thank you. but can you give me more details?

Comment: Ok I give you an example

Comment: Your controller method initializes a new `List<ModelDescription>` each time and adds just the one item to the collection and then you create a partial based on that collection. One option would be to include the `<table>` in the main view, and the partial is based on a single model - i.e. `@model ModelDescription` and generates just a `<tr>` element, and then you append it to the existing `<table>`.

Comment: But there is no reason to post back to a controller method (unless you want to save something because all the data you need is in the DOM already. You can just get the selected options text and value, and create a `<tr>` element using javascript/jquery based on those values and append it to a <table>` element

Comment: yes, i will try to do it by using your suggestions. I will post it here once I'm done. thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to this link:

> I'm storing the list of emails in Session["emails"] and every time I add a new email to the list, I just update it a pass it to a new list with all the records and at the end return the partial view.

[.NET use partial view multiple times  @Rolando F](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40312495/9933218)

I've changed some of my codes:

**ModelDescription.cs**

```
public class ModelDescription
{
    public IEnumerable<string> modelsAdded { get; set; }
}
```

**AddToListSOH method in controller:**

```
 public ActionResult AddToListSOH(string model)
    {
        if (Session["modelInputs"] == null)
        {
            List<string> temphandler1 = new List<string>();
            temphandler1.Add(model);
            Session["modelInputs"] = temphandler1;
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> temphandler2 = new List<string>();
            temphandler2 = (List<string>)Session["modelInputs"];
            temphandler2.Add(model);
            Session["modelInputs"] = temphandler2;
        }

        var result = new ModelDescription { modelsAdded = (List<string>)Session["modelInputs"] }; 


        return PartialView("AddToListSOH", result);
    }
```

**AddToListSOH.cshtml (Partial View):**

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped" @*style="font-size: .7rem;"*@>
    <caption>List of Models</caption>
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.modelsAdded)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                   @count
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(i => item)
                </td>
                <td>
                    Remove
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example to make SelectListItem List

```
private List<SelectListItem> ModelDeskList(ModelDesk modelDesc)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "------Select-----",Selected=true });
            foreach (var model in modelDesc)
            {
                selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = model.Id.ToString(), Text = model.Name});
            }
            return selectList;
}
```

I hope you find your solution from it

Comment: That is not what OP is asking!

Comment: I already have the working codes for the dropdownlist. What I can't figure out is how to add the selected item to a List<> (table). thank you @Md. Abdul Alim.

Comment: According to rules of stack overflow you have no right to vote but you can accept answer. Which is in below down vote button

Comment: Sorry but I can't accept your answer because it does not solve my problem/question. thanks